# Is it possible to control a User's Role based on their Email Address?

Tags: emails, users

Currently I am emailed everytime time an employee at my company needs their account role upgraded to 'Authenticated' to 'Employee', any suggestions on a way to automate that process?

Thanks!

Comment: You have to provide much more information about your setup.

Comment: I agree with @tunic - we need to know what this decision is based on, and who is allowed to make it, to help you with automation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Auto Assign Role" and "Apply for role" modules seem to be close to what you are asking for.

https://www.drupal.org/project/autoassignrole
https://www.drupal.org/project/apply_for_role

If they don't fit your exact use case then I suggest looking at the way `autoassignrole_user_presave()` works as a starting point for custom coding. http://cgit.drupalcode.org/autoassignrole/tree/autoassignrole.module#n183

Comment: Thank you so much! This is extremely helpful, I really feel like I'm plunging into some foreign territory and these both sound like excellent starting points for me!